# 1 global function or many instance functions

Tags: ios, swift

If there are two similar classes that need the same function. Is it better to write the function globally, or write the same function twice inside each of the classes. Ex.

**Option 1: two instance functions**

```
class A {

    func buttonTapped() {
        upvote(id)
    }

    func upvote(postID:String) {
        // upvote the post
    }
}

class B {

    func buttonTapped() {
        upvote(id)
    }

    func upvote(postID:String) {
        // upvote the post
    }
}
```

**Option 2: one global function**

```
class A {
    func buttonTapped() {
        upvote(id)
    }
}

class B {
    func buttonTapped() {
        upvote(id)
    }
}

func upvote(postID:string) {
        // upvote the post
}
```

Or is there a better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest neither.

You should have a data model class and the `upvote` function should be part of that class.

```
class Post {
    var postID: String
    public private(set) var votes: Int

    ...

    func upvote() {
        self.votes += 1
    }
}
```

Then you would call it as

```
 somePost.upvote()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. What's the advantage of having votes defined as get only versus having a `getVotes()` method?

Comment: Also is there an advantage to having this be a class over a struct?

Comment: There is no 'advantage' but semantically `votes` should be a property, not a function.  A function implies some sort of operation (such as up voting), so while you can use a getter function it is nicer to use a property.  Note that I just found a nicer way of creating a read-only property so I updated my answer.

Comment: You could create a struct with `upvote` as a mutating function. But you probably want reference type semantics  for a post.  For example if `Post` is a struct then calling `upvote` will mutate the struct and any other variables that have (or rather had) the same `Post` will not see the new vote count since structs are copy-on-write

Comment: I agree this answer is the simplest one for the scope you proposed, but checkout my answer for a more broad approach if your problem grows to be more complex.

Comment: @CaioTomazelli I did consider an protocol-based solution, but it seemed in this case that the OP has combined UI and data model and that is the main problem.  Now, the `Post` class could implement `Votable` but that seemed like it would just be adding complexity to the answer.  What if there aren't things other than Posts that need to be votable. If there are things that need to be Votable in the future then you can add the protocol and refactor

Comment: @Paulw11 perfect considerations, I totally agree that the main issue to be adressed in this questions was the mixing of data handling and UI! Also agree with the complexity factor of adding a protocol if only posts need the function, will edit my answer to include that ;)

Answer (score 3):

Someone suggested inheritance, but you should always consider `composition over inheritance` (more on the subject here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Maybe there are a lot of classes that could profit from an upvote method?
For instance, if you are implementing yet-another-instagram-clone, you could have `Stories` and `Posts` that could have the same interface for upvoting but it would be unwise of them to inherit from the same parent.

In this case, we could implement something like that:

```
protocol Votable {
  func upvote()
}

extension Votable {
  func upvote() {
    // do upvoting
  }
}
```

And then you can add this `trait` to your classes:

```
class A: Votable {
    func buttonTapped() {
        upvote(id)
    }
}

class B: Votable {
    func buttonTapped() {
        upvote(id)
    }
}
```

And there you go: same function implementation for both classes (or even different ones with the same interface if you want to implement other extensions to the same protocol) without class-inheritance.

Edit: As @Paulw11 pointed out, you should always go to the simpler solution in the beggining. If only `Posts` need an upvote method, don't mess around with inheritance or composition, implement the methods only where they're needed and then refactor accordingly with the evolution of your product.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a "parent"-class with the common functions, and then let class A and B inherit from the "parent"-class. Like this:

```
class Parent {
   func upvote(postID:String) {
        // upvote the post
    }
}

class A: Parent {

    func buttonTapped() {
        upvote(id)
    }

}

class B: Parent {

    func buttonTapped() {
        upvote(id)
    }
}
```